# what are the main differences between all the mysql engines?

Tags: mysql

I want to make a summary of the main differences between all the Mysql engines and of course the most populars also.

And what criteria should I use to determine which engine to use?

Comment: "what criteria should I use to determine which engine to use?" - wouldn't that depend on your specific requirements?

Comment: He's asking **how** to determine which engine he should use, not **which** engine he should use. It's a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 8):

They are very well described here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-engines.html

Use InnoDB, if you're in doubt. It is general-purpose and performs well.

Answer (score 4):

As Lars D says, This is very well described here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-engines.html

This data is from link given above which may help you a bit...

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
 Engine: MyISAM
Support: DEFAULT
Comment: Default engine as of MySQL 3.23 with great performance
*************************** 2. row ***************************
 Engine: MEMORY
Support: YES
Comment: Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables
*************************** 3. row ***************************
 Engine: HEAP
Support: YES
Comment: Alias for MEMORY
*************************** 4. row ***************************
 Engine: MERGE
Support: YES
Comment: Collection of identical MyISAM tables
*************************** 5. row ***************************
 Engine: MRG_MYISAM
Support: YES
Comment: Alias for MERGE
*************************** 6. row ***************************
 Engine: ISAM
Support: NO
Comment: Obsolete storage engine, now replaced by MyISAM
*************************** 7. row ***************************
 Engine: MRG_ISAM
Support: NO
Comment: Obsolete storage engine, now replaced by MERGE
*************************** 8. row ***************************
 Engine: InnoDB
Support: YES
Comment: Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys
*************************** 9. row ***************************
 Engine: INNOBASE
Support: YES
Comment: Alias for INNODB
*************************** 10. row ***************************
 Engine: BDB
Support: YES
Comment: Supports transactions and page-level locking
*************************** 11. row ***************************
 Engine: BERKELEYDB
Support: YES
Comment: Alias for BDB
*************************** 12. row ***************************
 Engine: NDBCLUSTER
Support: NO
Comment: Clustered, fault-tolerant, memory-based tables
*************************** 13. row ***************************
 Engine: NDB
Support: NO
Comment: Alias for NDBCLUSTER
*************************** 14. row ***************************
 Engine: EXAMPLE
Support: NO
Comment: Example storage engine
*************************** 15. row ***************************
 Engine: ARCHIVE
Support: YES
Comment: Archive storage engine
*************************** 16. row ***************************
 Engine: CSV
Support: NO
Comment: CSV storage engine
*************************** 17. row ***************************
 Engine: FEDERATED
Support: YES
Comment: Federated MySQL storage engine
*************************** 18. row ***************************
 Engine: BLACKHOLE
Support: YES
Comment: /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look to the manual, like Lars and Phil said.

Although, i could tell you in short, the differences between the primaries engines (MyISAM and innoDB) are in Transaction support, foraing key support, Locking level (MyISAM locks the entire table, innoDB has row level locking), and MVCC. There are too much many differences between them. I recommend you to take a look at: Pro MySQL Apress 2005.

--
Santiago Basulto.-