# Why MySQL server has multiple database engines

Tags: database, mysql-workbench

In one of my interviews I have been asked this question. Can someone explain this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what are the main differences between all the mysql engines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693961/what-are-the-main-differences-between-all-the-mysql-engines)

Answer (score 0):

In short words: to adapt the your data type to the best database management algorithms (optimization of searching and saving data etc.)